# Trouble getting print out instructions in Python classes

Tags: python, class, user-input

New to Python. Every time I run the following code in the terminal I get function review at 0x1004a4320 as the output. What am I doing wrong? I want the function in the classes to run and prompt the user for input.

class Review(object):

```
def enter(self):
    exit(1)
```

class userInput():

```
def __init__(self, review):
    self.review = review

def inputReview(self):
    review = ""
    print "Welcome to our review system! Please input review text below."
    while review == "":
        review = raw_input("> ")
        if review != "":
            print review
            exit(1)
        else:
            print review
```

a = userInput(Review)
a.inputReview()

Runs fine now but just wondering why the object class is needed. I know to put it in there but not why, if that makes any sense.

Comment: I tried editing your code block, but I worry that I got the indentation wrong. Do you really have a `print review` indented inside of `class getReview`, and not inside any `def`s or anything? When I run your code, I don't see '"', I see `<function review at 0x0000000002959B38>`.

Comment: What references/resources are you using to learn Python?

Comment: Also, don't name a class `Dict`. Just...don't. If you want a dictionary type, use the built-in `dict`.

Comment: As far as I can see you have an object named review, a method named review, a member named review and a local variable named review. This confusion of names is surely a factor in the problem you have encountered here. Try to get out of the habit of using the same name repeatedly. Running this through pylint would immediately alert you to problems.

Comment: indentation at the last `print review` is probably wrong

Comment: And...why do you have both a `Review` class and a `review` class?? And why is `getReview` (which sounds like a method name) used as a class name?? And what do you expect your `Review.enter` method to be doing?

Comment: LPTHW - and as far as the names I will go back through and use different names. The object Review was just made to create the object and as for the function within it it was simply a hold over from LPTHW. I suppose I could use pass on it instead. @KyleStrand

Comment: Er...if you're just going to `pass`, why do you even have a method? When you say "create the object," what do you mean by that? Defining the `Review` class, as I said in my answer, doesn't actually *create* any objects for you.

Comment: @KyleStrand You are right it is rather redundant. So when should I actually create a class(object) as opposed to a class()?

Comment: I"m not exactly sure what you mean by that. The syntax `class Name(foo):` is for defining a new class `Name` that *inherits from* `foo`. So `class Review(object):` is the start of the definition of the `Review` class, which inherits from `object` (which is...well, it's a silly problem that was fixed in Python3, and let's leave it at that). Similarly, `class getReview(Review):` is the start of the definition of the class `getReview`, which inherits from `Review` (and thereby indirectly inherits from `object`). In neither case are you *creating an object*.

Comment: Note that `class Review:` would *also* be the beginning of the definition of the `Review` class; the only difference is that `Review` would no longer inherit from `object`.

Comment: @KyleStrand well I cleaned up the code and got it running. Interestingly, at least to me, is that when I eliminated the class Review(object) i was given a __init__  2 needed (1 given) argument error. Placing the Review(object) class cleared it right up and printed what I wanted. Why is that?

Comment: @JCD There's quite a bit of code you're not showing me. You did substantially more than "clean up" the code if it's now working as you expected it to work, so I really don't have any way to know why you're seeing the behaviors you're seeing. In general, the error you're describing means that you somehow defined an `__init__` method with additional arguments (beyond `self`). (Also, please start surrounding things like error messages with backticks: `\``)

Comment: I'm not really sure how you expect me to read that without indenting. Please edit your original question to add it; comments aren't really made for that sort of thing.

Comment: @KyleStrand alright my mistake. Its up now.

Comment: Also make sure *all* code is indented at least 4 spaces (more than that for actual indents in the code; e.g., your `def enter(self):` should be indented 8 spaces). I'll do it for you this time, but you should compare it to what you initially wrote for future reference.

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to save my edits. In any case, you now have an `__init__` method that, as I said, takes an additional argument beyond `self`. This is unrelated to the fact that `Review` inherits from `object`. Note that the `def __init__(self, review):` syntax means that, when initializing a `userInput` object, an *argument* (called `review`) is necessary. This is different from the *inheritance* syntax of `class Review(object)`, which (currently) isn't really doing anything. You then pass the *class* (*not* a class instance) to the `userInput.__init__` method.

Comment: This class is then assigned to the instance variable `a.review`, which is never used again. In short, you can remove the `Review` class definition and the `__init__` method definition, then remove the `Review` argument from the line `a = userInput(Review)`, and the code will still behave in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are like molds for creating new things. In order to actually *use* them, (in most cases) you need to create "instances" of each class. In Python, the way you do this is with the following syntax:

```
myobj = myClass()
```

...where `myClass` is the name of the class (e.g., `Review`) and `myobj` is the name of the new class *instance*.

`def` statements inside a class define *methods*. These are called via the *instances* of the class: e.g., `r = Review; r.enter()` will cause the `enter` method in the `r` object, which is an instance of the `Review` class, to be called. Equivalently (in this case), it will cause the `enter` method in the `Review` class to be called with the instance `r` as a first argument (this is the `self` argument).

So in order to actually do anything, you need to actually have some code to instantiate objects at the end of your script. For instance:

```
g = getReview()
g.review()
```